# how to convert a multiple python files into one ipynb file?

Tags: python, jupyter

im trying to convert four python files that are related (belongs to the same project) into a jupyter notebook(ipynb) one file , is there any specific way to do that ?
This is my project folder tree:
C:/
build_dataset.py
train_model.py
folder1
---cancernet.py
---config.py
dataset_folder

Answer (score 0):

You can use py2nb tool for it:

https://github.com/williamjameshandley/py2nb

Just call it from the shell:

`py2nb waka.py`

and you will get the `.ipynb` file.

PS: There are several similar tools. [p2j](https://pypi.org/project/p2j/) also can help you. Usage is absolutely equal to `py2nb`. Or you can use the powerful [jupytext](https://github.com/mwouts/jupytext) with its command line conversions between formats:

```
jupytext --to notebook notebook.py              # overwrite notebook.ipynb (remove outputs)
jupytext --to notebook --update notebook.py     # update notebook.ipynb (preserve outputs)
jupytext --to ipynb notebook1.md notebook2.py   # overwrite notebook1.ipynb and notebook2.ipynb
```

Comment: Sorry but none of your solutions work. They're far from what OP asked